# exit(1) in child process returns 256 in the parent process in Linux

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I am new to OS programming. I am trying to figure out the mechanism of process creation using fork() system call in Linux. Hence I have written the following code.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Child can't be created\n");
    } else if(pid == 0) {
        printf("Hi I am child : %d\n",getpid());
        printf("Child finished\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Hi! I am parent : %d\n",getpid());
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf("After that parent get : %d of child %d\n",status,pid);
        printf("Parent finished\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to my knowledge, the parent process gets the exit status of its child process after its termination via the wait() system call. When I am passing 0 to the exit() function in the child process, the parent is also getting 0 as the status. But when I pass 1, the parent process is getting 256. Here is a snapshot of the output for reference.
[image]

**My question is why it is happenning and how? Please explain.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the status value from `wait` contains just the exit value?

Comment: Maybe my intuition is wrong then, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: [The documentation of `wait()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) explains how to get the collected process's exit status from the status code `wait()` provides.  You should not be relying on intuition for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

The value that `wait` puts in `status` is not just the exit status. To get the exit status from it, you need to use the `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` macros.  eg:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if( pid < 0 ){
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    } else if( pid == 0 ){
        printf("Hi I am child : %ld\n", (long)getpid());
        printf("Child finished\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Hi! I am parent : %ld\n", (long)getpid());
        pid = wait(&status);
        if( WIFEXITED(status) ){
            printf("parent get: %d of child %ld\n",
                WEXITSTATUS(status), (long)pid
            );
        }
        printf("Parent finished\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```